# Swift + Firebase: Storing, retrieving, and using an array of document references

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

I'm relatively new to Swift and Firebase, so I'm not very familiar with the intricacies of how both work together. I'm building a chat app that has messages and threads. A user can send a message, `struct Message`, and if another user wants to directly reply to that message, a thread is created. For each message, I'm storing an array of Firebase document references to the other messages in the thread, `threadBefore: [Message]`.

```
struct Message: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var content: String
    var name: String
    var upvotes: Int
    var likedByUser: Bool
    var dontShow: Bool
    var sentAt: Date
    var threadsArray: [Message]
}
```

The following is my code for fetching all the chat messages from Firebase:
`dontShow` property: if `dontShow == true` means that the message is inside the thread and shouldn't be displayed like a regular message in the chat. However, the very last message in the thread is displayed and has `dontShow = false`.

```
func fetchMessages(docId: String, collectionType: String, isThreadMember: Bool) {
        if (user != nil) {
            db.collection("chatrooms").document(docId).collection(collectionType).order(by: "sentAt", descending: false).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No messages")
                    return
                }
                
//                let threadsTemp: [Message]()
                let classroomId = docId
                if !isThreadMember {
                    if collectionType == "messages" {
                        self.messages = documents.map { doc -> Message in
                            let data = doc.data()
                            let docId1 = doc.documentID
                            let content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
                            let displayName = data["displayName"] as? String ?? ""
                            let likedUsersArr = data["likedUsers"] as? Array ?? [""]
                            // if message is in thread (but not last message), then don't show as normal message, but in thread
                            let dontShow = data["dontShow"] as? Bool ?? false
                            let sentAt = data["sentAt"] as? Date ?? Date()
                            let threadBefore = data["threadBefore"] as? [DocumentReference] ?? [DocumentReference]()
                            
                            // using reference array
                            if dontShow == false {
                                if (threadBefore.count > 0) {
                                    // reset the temporary array that holds the threads to be added afterwards
                                    self.threadsTemp = []
                                    for docRef in threadBefore {
                                        docRef.getDocument { (doc2, error) in
                                            if let doc2 = doc2, doc2.exists {
                                                let docId2 = doc2.documentID
                                                self.fetchThreadMessages(classroomId: classroomId, parentMessageId: docId1, docId: docId2)
                                            } else {
                                                print("Document does not exist")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            return Message(id: docId1,
                                           content: content,
                                           name: displayName,
                                           upvotes: likedUsersArr.count,
                                           likedByUser: likedUsersArr.contains(self.user!.uid) ? true : false,
                                           dontShow: dontShow,
                                           sentAt: sentAt,
                                           threadsArray: self.threadsTemp)
                        }
                    }
```

Another function: `fetchThreadMessages`:

```
// fetch a specified message and then append to the temporary threads array, threadsTemp
    func fetchThreadMessages(classroomId: String, parentMessageId: String, docId: String) -> Message {
        if (user != nil) {
            let docRef = db.collection("chatrooms").document(classroomId).collection("messages").document(docId)
            docRef.getDocument { (doc, error) in
                if let doc = doc, doc.exists {
                    if let data = doc.data(){
                        let docId = doc.documentID
                        print("docid")
                        print(docId)
                        let content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
                        let displayName = data["displayName"] as? String ?? ""
                        let likedUsersArr = data["likedUsers"] as? Array ?? [""]
                        // if message is in thread (but not last message), then don't show as normal message, but in thread
                        let dontShow = data["dontShow"] as? Bool ?? false
                        let sentAt = data["sentAt"] as? Date ?? Date()
                        
                        self.threadsTemp.append(Message(id: docId,
                                                        content: content,
                                                        name: displayName,
                                                        upvotes: likedUsersArr.count,
                                                        likedByUser: likedUsersArr.contains(self.user!.uid) ? true : false,
                                                        dontShow: true,
                                                        sentAt: sentAt,
                                                        threadsArray: []))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't implemented how the `sendMessage()` function updates the `threadBefore` array, but I'm currently updating this field directly on Firebase just for testing.

```
func sendMessage(messageContent: String, docId: String, collectionType: String, isReply: Bool, threadId: String) {
        if (user != nil) {
            if isReply {
                let docRef = db.collection("chatrooms").document(docId).collection(collectionType).document(threadId)
                self.threadRef = db.document(docRef.path)
            }
            db.collection("chatrooms").document(docId).collection(collectionType).addDocument(data: [
                "sentAt": Date(),
                "displayName": user!.email ?? "",
                "content": messageContent,
                "likedUsers": [String](),
                "sender": user!.uid,
                "threadBefore": isReply ? [threadRef] : [DocumentReference](),
                "dontShow": false])
        }
    }
```

A little bit more on how I'm fetching and retrieving the document references from `threadsBefore`: For each `message` in the collection, I loop its `threadsArray`, which consists of `DocumentReferences` to other messesages that are in that thread. For each of those document references, I run `self.fetchThreadMessages`. This retrieves that message and stores a Message() instance in `threadsTemp`. Then, back in `self.fetchMessage`, when I'm done filling up the `self.threadsTemp` with all of the documents retrieved from `threadsBefore`, I store it in `threadsArray` property in the `Message` struct.

Now, look at the return state in `self.fetchMessages` above, the very last assignment inside `Message()` is `threadsArray: self.threadsTemp`. But the problem here is that this is just a reference? And it would change based on the last assignment to `self.threadsTemp`?

I've tried multiple ways to implement this entire storing and retrieving thing. But all came with several complicated errors. I tried using dictionaries, or storing just the document id's for the thread messages and then look them up in `self.Messages` (since it has all of the messages stored in it).

What's the best way to implement this? Or fix my errors?
I know my code is probably a mishmash of inefficient and confused coding practices. But I'm trying to learn.

Comment: As you seem to be aware, your question is pretty elaborate and tedious to sort through (hence why you probably didn't get any responses). A couple of tips for writing effective questions: (1) Keep your lines in your code to fit the width of the box, so that users don't have to continually scroll right and left to read each line code. (2) Try to focus your question a little more. It's difficult to get a full grasp of what your asking without going through every part of your (very long) question.

Answer (score 0):

With that being said (meaning, my comment above), I'm going to not as much address your code as I am going to propose what I think is a good way to organize your Firestore database for a chat app. Then, hopefully you will be able to apply it to your own situation.

First things first, we have to remember that Firestore charges based on the number of queries you make - it does not take into account the amount of data that is being fetched in a particular query - so fetching a single word is as expensive as fetching an entire novel. As such, we should structure our database in a way that is financially efficient.

What I would do personally is structure my database with two primary sections, (1) conversation threads and (2) users. Each user contains references to their threads they are a part of, and each thread contains a reference to the users that are in that thread. That way we can easily and efficiently fetch a user's conversations, or obtain the users in a particular conversation.

```
// COL = Collection
// DOC = Document

Threads (COL)
  Thread1 (DOC)
    id: String // id of the thread
    participants: [String: String] = [
      user1: [
        "username": "Bob23",
        "userID": IJ238KD... // the document id of the user
      ]
    ] // Keep this "participants" dictionary in the root of the thread 
      // document so we have easy access to fetch any user we want, if
      // we so desire (like if the user clicks to view the profile of a
      // user in the chat.
    Messages (COL)
      Message1 (DOC)
        from: String // id of user that sent message
      Message2 (DOC)
        ...
      ...
  Thread 2 (DOC)
    ...
  ...

Users (COL)
  User1 (DOC)
    threadIDs: [String] // Contains the thread "id"s of all the threads
                        // the user is a part of. (You probably want to 
                        // use a dictionary instead since array's can be
                        // difficult to work with in a database, but for
                        // simplicity, I'm going to use an array here.)
  User2 (DOC)
    ...
  ...
```

Now, let's say the user opens the app and we need to fetch their conversation threads. It's as easy as

```
db.collection("Threads").whereField("id", in: user.threadIDs)
```

**[EDIT]** *`user.threads` would be a local array of type `String`. You should have this data on hand since you would be fetching the current user's `User` document on app launch, which is why we include this data in that user document.*

Basically, this query returns every document in the `Threads` collection whose "id" field exists in the array of the user's threadIDs (which is an array of type String). You can read more about Firestore queries in their docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

In other words, we get every thread document that the user has references to.

The great thing about this is that it takes only one query to return all of the conversations of a user.

Now let's say the user is scrolling through their conversation threads in the app, and they tap one of them to open up the messages. Now, all we do is fetch all the messages in that particular thread, again only requiring one query to do so.

Last but not least, if for some reason we have to get info about a particular user in a conversation, we have all the references we need within that thread document itself to fetch the user data, if needed.

Comment: You put a lot of thought into this answer and that's awesome. Generally speaking, it's on point. A couple of things; This `.whereField("id", in: user.threadIDs)` won't work. Firestore doesn't have a way to automatically 'know' what `user.threadID's` is. Each threadID would need to be queried for separately which obviously is a lot more work. While you *could* use [array-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) to query for some theadID's, it's limited to 10, so that won't really work either. Also, there are no dictionaries in Firestore

Comment: I was assuming `user.threadIDs` was an array you already had locally since you would have already obtained this data from the initial user document fetch performed on app launch. I'll add a comment in my response to clarify.

Comment: Secondly, Firestore allows maps (Firebase equivalent of a Swift dictionary imo) ([https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model] so that's what I was referring to by "dictionary".

Comment: Lastly, I did not know array-in was limited to 10, so thanks for pointing that out. Since I come from more of a Firebase Realtime background, I wouldn't be surprised if there were some minor improvements to be made here or there; but as you've mentioned, I think the overall approach is what counts. Thanks!

Comment: Good edit. But: the number of child nodes or documents is often unknown. Loading *all* of those could potentially be an enormous amount of data and overwhelm the device causing crashes; loading thread id's into an array would not be safely scaleable. Also, *this query returns every document in the Threads collection whose "id" field exists in the array* will not work. Firebase can't load data based on what's in an array without implicitly iterating over each element. A better option is to store users id's in each thread doc at a high level and query threads.userid's that match this userId

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same thing? It would still have to iterate over every single thread doc to find which contain the userID. I guess I'm not completely aware of what is considered an efficient operation in Firestore.

Comment: No, not the same thing at all. There is no iteration when performing a query as the server performs the query and returns (all/some of) the data. The important thing is how the app handles that data. Using [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) you can specify the amount of data that's returned at one time - protecting your code and preventing the device from being overwhelmed.